# "Warning: count()" error on php 7.2

Tags: php, warnings

I'm currently working with php 7.2 and when I use get_the_content() or get_the_excerpt() outside of a single template, in the functions.php for example, I get the following Warning:

*Warning:  count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/wp-kona/wp-includes/post-template.php on line 284*

What's wrong with it?  Is it a wordpress core bug? Am I missing something.

Comment: What is your full use of the function?

Comment: Are you calling these functions outside the loop?

Comment: I think this is unimportant.  I'm just using it to check if the content has some specefic shortcode for example.
Yes, it's outside the loop.  But how can I access to the content (with the id) then outside the loop.

Comment: Can you show the specific usage that is causing the issue. To rule out any syntax issues or incorrect usage of the function.

Comment: This is a bug in core WP. See https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/42814

Comment: That's bad, so we need to wait until they fixed it and release the new version.

Comment: am experiencing the same issue. Appears to be a compatibility issue. It is possible that the values being passed to count() are null or false.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I already knew the cause of what you're experiencing:

## The $page and $pages global variable have not been set up and a call to `get_the_content` or `get_the_excerpt` would return that error: count(pages)

That said, pages global variable is set to null, calling count(pages) triggers that error because a null value cannot be counted.

To fix this, one can easily tell that you're calling `get_the_content` or `get_the_excerpt` outside the loop.

So you have to set up the post data correctly before usage, that's what the loop is meant to do:

```
while ( have_post(): the_post() ) :
    // get_the_content() or get_the_excerpt() will work fine now
    the_content();
endwhile;
```

Comment: This answer does not address the OP's PHP error related to the `count()` function.

Comment: I've already stated why count() trigger that error. The `http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php` count() function counts all elements in an array or something in an object. Anything else will throw an error.

Comment: @benmay to explore this error, set the $page and $pages global var before calling `get_the_content()` or `get_the_excerpt()` and see what happens next: `global $post; $page, $pages; $pages = 1; $page = 1;` Now call `get_the_content()` and see for yourself.

Comment: Thanks for helping me see that answer John! I deleted my answer because it was based on a misunderstanding of the issue and didn't solve the problem.

Comment: @JustinWaulters you are welcome. Glad I could be of little help

Comment: This is a typical cause of the error. For more information refer WordPress Loop https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop

Answer (score 1):

As of v5.2, this will no longer be an issue.  `get_the_content()` and `wp_trim_excerpt()` are getting an optional new parameter (third and second respectively) of `$post` so you can use it outside the loop, bringing it in line with the functionality of all the other `get_the_*` functions.  It only took 16 years...  [Reference on Trac](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/44941)

Answer (score 0):

This bug related to WordPress core bug
https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/42814

Most often it occurs when you call the function `get_the_excerpt` or `get_the_content` outside the Loop provided that excerpt or content is empty.

So to fix it yourself you should find error place and check excerpt/content existing manually.

For example:

```
if(has_excerpt($post_id)) {
    $meta[] = sprintf('<meta name="description" content="%s">',
        get_the_excerpt($post_id)
    );
}
```

Comment: Please see this comment on the page you linked to: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/42814#comment:16 - seems like this exact issue. They still can not reproduce it as an issue with WP core. I my memory serves me right `count()` used to show a notice if you gave it a string, now it seems to be a warning.

Answer (score 0):

If someone bumps in to this issue, the solution is to get the_content from the meta field and run it trough the_content filter like this:

`apply_filters('the_content', get_post_field('post_content', $post->id));`

I made a short video explayining the whole thing if you wait untill the TLDR section...
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vMguTNzFoUk